# Генерация условий python telebot

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

у меня есть вот такой кусок кода, испрльзуется библиотека telebot:

```
keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
keyboard.row('Какая то кнопка')

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите название для новой кнопки')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, add_button)

def add_button(message):
    msg = message.text
    keyboard.row(f'{msg}')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Кнопка добавлена', reply_markup = keyboard)
```

Мне нужно что бы при нажатии на кнопку выполнялось определенное действие, я делал это так:

```
if message.text == 'Кнопка':
    #выполняется какое то действие
elif message.text == 'Другая кнопка':
    #выполняется другое действие
```

Проблема состоит в том, что новые кнопки добавлять я могу, а как им присвоить функционал, как осуществить это через условные операторы я не понимаю, возможно вопрос глупый и поставлен не правильно, но тем не менее, знающие ребята, посоветйте что нибудь

Answer (score 0):

*Вот исправленный код*

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.Telebot('TOKEN BOT')

keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
keyboard.row('Какая то кнопка')

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите название для новой кнопки')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, add_button)

def add_button(message):
    msg = message.text
    keyboard.row(f'{msg}')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Кнопка добавлена', reply_markup=keyboard)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def text(message):
    if message.text == 'Кнопка':
        #выполняется какое то действие
    elif message.text == 'Другая кнопка':
        #выполняется другое действие


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: вероятно, более полезным было бы написать, что именно у автора вопроса «не так».